# Проблемы с отображением view в главном классе

Tags: java, android, view

Размер view равен нулю по X и Y. Когда устанавливаю размеры через LayoutParams, то view отображается только если размеры равны LayoutParams.MARCH_PARENT для X и Y.
Но в этом случае, последняя добавленная view перекрывает остальные, и не даёт с ними взаимодействовать. Как решить?

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_play);

    AbsoluteLayout rlPlay = (AbsoluteLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlPlay);
    GamePlace gp = new GamePlace(this);

    Protect1 pt1 = new Protect1(this);

    Protect1 pt2 = new Protect1(this);

    pt1.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    pt2.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    Toast.makeText(this, pt1.getHeight() + " : " + pt1.getWidth(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    rlPlay.addView(gp);
    rlPlay.addView(pt1);
    pt2.setCoord(490, 350);
    rlPlay.addView(pt2);

}
```

}

Comment: не ставить последней вьюхе размер в `ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT` (что означает на весь экран)

Answer (score 0):

MARCH_PARENT - занимает всё свободное место, используйте wrap_content